# Sorting countries by name

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am using an API to get list of countries, states and cities at select inputs in a website.  The API used is a github repository https://github.com/hiiamrohit/Countries-States-Cities-database

Countries, states and cities are sorted by id by default, I have tried to sort them by name, but the result is the same, i don't understand why.
Here is the code for countries as example of my issue:

**HTML**

```
<script src="js/location.js"></script> 

  <select class="form-control countries" id="countryId" name="countryId" onchange="cambiar_pais_mapa()">

  </select>
```

**JS**
js/location.js

```
    this.getCountries = function() {
    var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCountries';
    var method = "post";
    var data = {};
    $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Procesando..");
    call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
        $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Selecciona un pais");
        console.log(data);
        if(data.tp == 1){
            $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                var option = $('<option />');
                option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                $('.countries').append(option);
            });
            $(".countries").prop("disabled",false);
        }
        else{
            alert(data.msg);
        }
    }); 
};
```

**PHP**

classes/location.php

```
 // Fetch all countries list
   public static function getCountries() {
     try {
       $query = "SELECT id, name FROM countries ORDER BY name ASC";
       $result = dbconfig::run($query);
       if(!$result) {
         throw new exception("Country not found.");
       }
       $res = array();
       while($resultSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $res[$resultSet['id']] = $resultSet['name'];
       }
       $data = array('status'=>'success', 'tp'=>1, 'msg'=>"Countries fetched successfully.", 'result'=>$res);
     } catch (Exception $e) {
       $data = array('status'=>'error', 'tp'=>0, 'msg'=>$e->getMessage());
     } finally {
        return $data;
     }
   }
```

I don't see any reason to not order the countries by name. I have added two new countries at the MySQL table, and they are always put at the end of the result.

Any help is welcome

**EDIT**

console log for

> console.log(JSON.stringify(data["result"]))

```
{"1":"Afghanistan","2":"Albania","3":"Algeria","4":"American Samoa","5":"Andorra","6":"Angola","7":"Anguilla","8":"Antarctica","9":"Antigua And Barbuda","10":"Argentina","11":"Armenia","12":"Aruba","13":"Australia","14":"Austria","15":"Azerbaijan","16":"Bahamas The","17":"Bahrain","18":"Bangladesh","19":"Barbados","20":"Belarus","21":"Belgium","22":"Belize","23":"Benin","24":"Bermuda","25":"Bhutan","26":"Bolivia","27":"Bosnia and Herzegovina","28":"Botswana","29":"Bouvet Island","30":"Brazil","31":"British Indian Ocean Territory","32":"Brunei","33":"Bulgaria","34":"Burkina Faso","35":"Burundi","36":"Cambodia","37":"Cameroon","38":"Canada","39":"Cape Verde","40":"Cayman Islands","41":"Central African Republic","42":"Chad","43":"Chile","44":"China","45":"Christmas Island","46":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands","47":"Colombia","48":"Comoros","49":"Congo","50":"Congo The Democratic Republic Of The","51":"Cook Islands","52":"Costa Rica","53":"Cote D'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)","54":"Croatia (Hrvatska)","55":"Cuba","56":"Cyprus","57":"Czech Republic","58":"Denmark","59":"Djibouti","60":"Dominica","61":"Dominican Republic","62":"East Timor","63":"Ecuador","64":"Egypt","65":"El Salvador","66":"Equatorial Guinea","67":"Eritrea","68":"Estonia","69":"Ethiopia","70":"External Territories of Australia","71":"Falkland Islands","72":"Faroe Islands","73":"Fiji Islands","74":"Finland","75":"France","76":"French Guiana","77":"French Polynesia","78":"French Southern Territories","79":"Gabon","80":"Gambia The","81":"Georgia","82":"Germany","83":"Ghana","84":"Gibraltar","85":"Greece","86":"Greenland","87":"Grenada","88":"Guadeloupe","89":"Guam","90":"Guatemala","91":"Guernsey and Alderney","92":"Guinea","93":"Guinea-Bissau","94":"Guyana","95":"Haiti","96":"Heard and McDonald Islands","97":"Honduras","98":"Hong Kong S.A.R.","99":"Hungary","100":"Iceland","101":"India","102":"Indonesia","103":"Iran","104":"Iraq","105":"Ireland","106":"Israel","107":"Italy","108":"Jamaica","109":"Japan","110":"Jersey","111":"Jordan","112":"Kazakhstan","113":"Kenya","114":"Kiribati","115":"Korea North","116":"Korea South","117":"Kuwait","118":"Kyrgyzstan","119":"Laos","120":"Latvia","121":"Lebanon","122":"Lesotho","123":"Liberia","124":"Libya","125":"Liechtenstein","126":"Lithuania","127":"Luxembourg","128":"Macau S.A.R.","129":"Macedonia","130":"Madagascar","131":"Malawi","132":"Malaysia","133":"Maldives","134":"Mali","135":"Malta","136":"Man (Isle of)","137":"Marshall Islands","138":"Martinique","139":"Mauritania","140":"Mauritius","141":"Mayotte","142":"Mexico","143":"Micronesia","144":"Moldova","145":"Monaco","146":"Mongolia","147":"Montserrat","148":"Morocco","149":"Mozambique","150":"Myanmar","151":"Namibia","152":"Nauru","153":"Nepal","154":"Netherlands Antilles","155":"Netherlands The","156":"New Caledonia","157":"New Zealand","158":"Nicaragua","159":"Niger","160":"Nigeria","161":"Niue","162":"Norfolk Island","163":"Northern Mariana Islands","164":"Norway","165":"Oman","166":"Pakistan","167":"Palau","168":"Palestinian Territory Occupied","169":"Panama","170":"Papua new Guinea","171":"Paraguay","172":"Peru","173":"Philippines","174":"Pitcairn Island","175":"Poland","176":"Portugal","177":"Puerto Rico","178":"Qatar","179":"Reunion","180":"Romania","181":"Russia","182":"Rwanda","183":"Saint Helena","184":"Saint Kitts And Nevis","185":"Saint Lucia","186":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon","187":"Saint Vincent And The Grenadines","188":"Samoa","189":"San Marino","190":"Sao Tome and Principe","191":"Saudi Arabia","192":"Senegal","193":"Serbia","194":"Seychelles","195":"Sierra Leone","196":"Singapore","197":"Slovakia","198":"Slovenia","199":"Smaller Territories of the UK","200":"Solomon Islands","201":"Somalia","202":"South Africa","203":"South Georgia","204":"South Sudan","205":"Spain","206":"Sri Lanka","207":"Sudan","208":"Suriname","209":"Svalbard And Jan Mayen Islands","210":"Swaziland","211":"Sweden","212":"Switzerland","213":"Syria","214":"Taiwan","215":"Tajikistan","216":"Tanzania","217":"Thailand","218":"Togo","219":"Tokelau","220":"Tonga","221":"Trinidad And Tobago","222":"Tunisia","223":"Turkey","224":"Turkmenistan","225":"Turks And Caicos Islands","226":"Tuvalu","227":"Uganda","228":"Ukraine","229":"United Arab Emirates","230":"United Kingdom","231":"United States","232":"United States Minor Outlying Islands","233":"Uruguay","234":"Uzbekistan","235":"Vanuatu","236":"Vatican City State (Holy See)","237":"Venezuela","238":"Vietnam","239":"Virgin Islands (British)","240":"Virgin Islands (US)","241":"Wallis And Futuna Islands","242":"Western Sahara","243":"Yemen","244":"Yugoslavia","245":"Zambia","246":"Zimbabwe","249":"Afghanistan 2"}
```

Comment: What is `data["result"]`?

Comment: Can't really give you an answer without seeing what you're data looks like, but you probably want to use [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), assuming you're doing your sorting in javascript.

Comment: @guest271314, I am not sure, as said it is an API from a Github repository.  I guess data['result'] stores each pair of data [id, name] received from JSON array and then show them as option at the select input

Comment: @HaydenBraxton, data are a pair [id, name]. The sorting should be done not at JS, I assume that I could sort the data directly at the MySQL request, but it doesn't work

Comment: @mvasco _"I am not sure"_ Why have you not checked what `data["result"]` is? How can a solution be suggested without awareness of what the actual data is?

Comment: So you're saying you used `ORDER BY` in your query and it didn't work?

Comment: @guest271314, sorry, I have put a console log and the result is [Object, object], thats what I say I am not sure

Comment: @HaydenBraxton, exactly, as you can see in the PHP part of my question

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(data["result"]))` log at `console`?

Comment: @guest271314, done and published in my question, As you can see, there is a second entry for Afghanistan, Afghanistan 2 , that I included to check the sorting and that is not sorted after Afghanistan.

Comment: @mvasco You are trying to sort the values of object at `php`, not `javascript`, correct?

Comment: @guest271314,yes, but if the result is the same, i don't care to sort them at php or at JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for..in` loop, `Array.prototype.sort()`

```
var arr = [];
for (prop in data["result"]) {
  arr.push(data["result"][prop])
}

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b)
});
```

---

Updating original `javascript` at Question, including use of `Object.keys()` and adjusting to append `<option>` elements to `.countries` element

```
this.getCountries = function() {
  var url = rootUrl + '?type=getCountries';
  var method = "post";
  var data = {};
  $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Procesando..");
  call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
    $('.countries').find("option:eq(0)").html("Selecciona un pais");
    console.log(data);
    if (data.tp == 1) {
      var arr = [];
      for (prop in data["result"]) {
        arr.push({
          [prop]: data["result"][prop]
        })
      }

      arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[Object.keys(a)[0]].localeCompare(b[Object.keys(b)[0]])
      });

      $.each(arr, function(key, val) {
        var option = $('<option />');
        var prop = Object.keys(val)[0];
        option.attr('value', prop).text(val[prop]);
        $('.countries').append(option);
      });
      $(".countries").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      alert(data.msg);
    }
  });
};
```

```js
var data = {
  "result": {
    "1": "Afghanistan",
    "2": "Albania",
    "3": "Algeria",
    "4": "American Samoa",
    "5": "Andorra",
    "6": "Angola",
    "7": "Anguilla",
    "8": "Antarctica",
    "9": "Antigua And Barbuda",
    "10": "Argentina",
    "11": "Armenia",
    "12": "Aruba",
    "13": "Australia",
    "14": "Austria",
    "15": "Azerbaijan",
    "16": "Bahamas The",
    "17": "Bahrain",
    "18": "Bangladesh",
    "19": "Barbados",
    "20": "Belarus",
    "21": "Belgium",
    "22": "Belize",
    "23": "Benin",
    "24": "Bermuda",
    "25": "Bhutan",
    "26": "Bolivia",
    "27": "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    "28": "Botswana",
    "29": "Bouvet Island",
    "30": "Brazil",
    "31": "British Indian Ocean Territory",
    "32": "Brunei",
    "33": "Bulgaria",
    "34": "Burkina Faso",
    "35": "Burundi",
    "36": "Cambodia",
    "37": "Cameroon",
    "38": "Canada",
    "39": "Cape Verde",
    "40": "Cayman Islands",
    "41": "Central African Republic",
    "42": "Chad",
    "43": "Chile",
    "44": "China",
    "45": "Christmas Island",
    "46": "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
    "47": "Colombia",
    "48": "Comoros",
    "49": "Congo",
    "50": "Congo The Democratic Republic Of The",
    "51": "Cook Islands",
    "52": "Costa Rica",
    "53": "Cote D'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)",
    "54": "Croatia (Hrvatska)",
    "55": "Cuba",
    "56": "Cyprus",
    "57": "Czech Republic",
    "58": "Denmark",
    "59": "Djibouti",
    "60": "Dominica",
    "61": "Dominican Republic",
    "62": "East Timor",
    "63": "Ecuador",
    "64": "Egypt",
    "65": "El Salvador",
    "66": "Equatorial Guinea",
    "67": "Eritrea",
    "68": "Estonia",
    "69": "Ethiopia",
    "70": "External Territories of Australia",
    "71": "Falkland Islands",
    "72": "Faroe Islands",
    "73": "Fiji Islands",
    "74": "Finland",
    "75": "France",
    "76": "French Guiana",
    "77": "French Polynesia",
    "78": "French Southern Territories",
    "79": "Gabon",
    "80": "Gambia The",
    "81": "Georgia",
    "82": "Germany",
    "83": "Ghana",
    "84": "Gibraltar",
    "85": "Greece",
    "86": "Greenland",
    "87": "Grenada",
    "88": "Guadeloupe",
    "89": "Guam",
    "90": "Guatemala",
    "91": "Guernsey and Alderney",
    "92": "Guinea",
    "93": "Guinea-Bissau",
    "94": "Guyana",
    "95": "Haiti",
    "96": "Heard and McDonald Islands",
    "97": "Honduras",
    "98": "Hong Kong S.A.R.",
    "99": "Hungary",
    "100": "Iceland",
    "101": "India",
    "102": "Indonesia",
    "103": "Iran",
    "104": "Iraq",
    "105": "Ireland",
    "106": "Israel",
    "107": "Italy",
    "108": "Jamaica",
    "109": "Japan",
    "110": "Jersey",
    "111": "Jordan",
    "112": "Kazakhstan",
    "113": "Kenya",
    "114": "Kiribati",
    "115": "Korea North",
    "116": "Korea South",
    "117": "Kuwait",
    "118": "Kyrgyzstan",
    "119": "Laos",
    "120": "Latvia",
    "121": "Lebanon",
    "122": "Lesotho",
    "123": "Liberia",
    "124": "Libya",
    "125": "Liechtenstein",
    "126": "Lithuania",
    "127": "Luxembourg",
    "128": "Macau S.A.R.",
    "129": "Macedonia",
    "130": "Madagascar",
    "131": "Malawi",
    "132": "Malaysia",
    "133": "Maldives",
    "134": "Mali",
    "135": "Malta",
    "136": "Man (Isle of)",
    "137": "Marshall Islands",
    "138": "Martinique",
    "139": "Mauritania",
    "140": "Mauritius",
    "141": "Mayotte",
    "142": "Mexico",
    "143": "Micronesia",
    "144": "Moldova",
    "145": "Monaco",
    "146": "Mongolia",
    "147": "Montserrat",
    "148": "Morocco",
    "149": "Mozambique",
    "150": "Myanmar",
    "151": "Namibia",
    "152": "Nauru",
    "153": "Nepal",
    "154": "Netherlands Antilles",
    "155": "Netherlands The",
    "156": "New Caledonia",
    "157": "New Zealand",
    "158": "Nicaragua",
    "159": "Niger",
    "160": "Nigeria",
    "161": "Niue",
    "162": "Norfolk Island",
    "163": "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "164": "Norway",
    "165": "Oman",
    "166": "Pakistan",
    "167": "Palau",
    "168": "Palestinian Territory Occupied",
    "169": "Panama",
    "170": "Papua new Guinea",
    "171": "Paraguay",
    "172": "Peru",
    "173": "Philippines",
    "174": "Pitcairn Island",
    "175": "Poland",
    "176": "Portugal",
    "177": "Puerto Rico",
    "178": "Qatar",
    "179": "Reunion",
    "180": "Romania",
    "181": "Russia",
    "182": "Rwanda",
    "183": "Saint Helena",
    "184": "Saint Kitts And Nevis",
    "185": "Saint Lucia",
    "186": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
    "187": "Saint Vincent And The Grenadines",
    "188": "Samoa",
    "189": "San Marino",
    "190": "Sao Tome and Principe",
    "191": "Saudi Arabia",
    "192": "Senegal",
    "193": "Serbia",
    "194": "Seychelles",
    "195": "Sierra Leone",
    "196": "Singapore",
    "197": "Slovakia",
    "198": "Slovenia",
    "199": "Smaller Territories of the UK",
    "200": "Solomon Islands",
    "201": "Somalia",
    "202": "South Africa",
    "203": "South Georgia",
    "204": "South Sudan",
    "205": "Spain",
    "206": "Sri Lanka",
    "207": "Sudan",
    "208": "Suriname",
    "209": "Svalbard And Jan Mayen Islands",
    "210": "Swaziland",
    "211": "Sweden",
    "212": "Switzerland",
    "213": "Syria",
    "214": "Taiwan",
    "215": "Tajikistan",
    "216": "Tanzania",
    "217": "Thailand",
    "218": "Togo",
    "219": "Tokelau",
    "220": "Tonga",
    "221": "Trinidad And Tobago",
    "222": "Tunisia",
    "223": "Turkey",
    "224": "Turkmenistan",
    "225": "Turks And Caicos Islands",
    "226": "Tuvalu",
    "227": "Uganda",
    "228": "Ukraine",
    "229": "United Arab Emirates",
    "230": "United Kingdom",
    "231": "United States",
    "232": "United States Minor Outlying Islands",
    "233": "Uruguay",
    "234": "Uzbekistan",
    "235": "Vanuatu",
    "236": "Vatican City State (Holy See)",
    "237": "Venezuela",
    "238": "Vietnam",
    "239": "Virgin Islands (British)",
    "240": "Virgin Islands (US)",
    "241": "Wallis And Futuna Islands",
    "242": "Western Sahara",
    "243": "Yemen",
    "244": "Yugoslavia",
    "245": "Zambia",
    "246": "Zimbabwe",
    "249": "Afghanistan 2"
  }
};

var arr = [];
for (prop in data["result"]) {
  arr.push({
    [prop]: data["result"][prop]
  })
}

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[Object.keys(a)[0]].localeCompare(b[Object.keys(b)[0]])
});

$.each(arr, function(key, val) {
  var option = $('<option />');
  var prop = Object.keys(val)[0];
  option.attr('value', prop).text(val[prop]);
  $('.countries').append(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="countries"></select>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6975mLw7/1/

Comment: And where should I implement your proposal? Inside  $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {   ?

Comment: Instead of `$.each(data["result"])`. Once array is sorted, you should then be able to append elements of array in order https://jsfiddle.net/6975mLw7/

Comment: Would you mind telling me how exactly to do it? I am not getting the elements of the array

Comment: Do you mean appending `<option>` elements to `document`?

Comment: I mean how to successfully update the original JS to include your proposal, I am not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a manual sort within your PHP `getCountries` Method like so:

```
<?php

    public static function getCountries() {
        try {
            $query  = "SELECT id, name FROM countries ORDER BY name ASC";
            $result = dbconfig::run($query);

            if(!$result) {
                throw new exception("Country not found.");
            }

            $res        = array();

            while($resultSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $res[$resultSet['id']] = $resultSet['name'];
            }

            // SIMPLY SORT $res HERE:
            // FIRST FLIP THE ARRAY SO THAT THE KEYS BECOME THE VALUES:
            $res        = array_flip($res);

            // NOW SORT WITH KEYS:
            ksort($res);

            // AGAIN; FLIP THE ARRAY BACK TO THE ORIGINAL FORM:
            $res        = array_flip($res);

            $data = array(
                'status'    => 'success',
                'tp'        => 1,
                'msg'       => "Countries fetched successfully.",
                'result'    => $res
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $data = array('status'=>'error', 'tp'=>0, 'msg'=>$e->getMessage());
        } finally {
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but your proposal doesn't changed the situation